# Delphi 11.2 : The procedure entry point @System@Urlclient@TAsyncReadStream@Sbcctr$qqrv could not be located in the dynamic link library myProgram.exe

Tags: delphi

I just updated Delphi from 11.0 to 11.2 and I get this error on startup.
The program compiles ok.
I guess it's about the Indy installation.
Anyone have a solution please?

Comment: Please confirm, does it really say *... could not be located in the dynamic link library myProgram.exe* ? Do you get any other error messages?

Comment: Yes, where myProgram.exe means "c:\....\...\myRealProgramFileName". The error occurs immediately after starting without any other error before. And by closing the notification, the app quits without any more errors.

Comment: I havent compiled any Indy programs with 1..2 yet.  You could try one of the demo programs if there is one there for Indy.

Comment: "_on startup_" of what? Your program or Delphi? Are you sure this short description is enough so others can reproduce your problem? As in: does it happen with a new empty project, should "_on startup_" mean running that project's compiled EXE? Is is platform dependant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that you are compiling your app to use packages and the entry point indicated is not found.

I think you've copied the error message incorrectly, because it *should* be "@System@Net@Urlclient@TAsyncReadStream@Sbcctr$qqrv".  This appears to be a exported item that is new in the 11.2 rtl280.bpl.

It has nothing to do with Indy (the name of the bpl entry point would make that obvious).

Bottom line, you have a path problem and at runtime, your app is finding the 11.0 rtl280.bpl instead of the 11.2 version.

Comment: Yes, you are right I skipped "Net" in my question and you are right again with rtl280.bpl. I had a copy of previous version in the program's folder !